# Is using the null-coalescing operator in C# always redunant if defaulting to null?

Tags: c#, refactoring, simplify, null-coalescing-operator

In C# is

```
x = y ?? null;
```

always equivalent to

```
x = y;
```

if both x and y are nullable types?

I can't think of a reason why the first line of code would ever be needed over the second.

Comment: I was refactoring if statements using the null-coalescing operator and noticed that smart sense and refactor had no tips on the matter. I was curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, writing the line

```
x = y ?? null;
```

Seems silly, since the expression will return `null` if `y` is null (so basically returning `y`) and `y` otherwise.

Remember that the null-coalescing operator is *functionally* the same as writing:

```
x = y != null ? y : <whatever operand>
```

Or, of course (for those not familiar with the ternary operator):

```
if (y != null)
   x = y;
else
   x = <whatever operand>;
```

In either case, using the null as the second argument has no utility whatsoever. You might as well just assign the variable, as noted in your post.

Comment: @GrantWinney, my mistake. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: could you not do something like this as well `if( x ?? y) == null`

Comment: @DJKRAZE, That statement would be equivalant to `if (x == null && y == null)`. Its a very odd way of writing that statement, so I wouldn't recommend it. What were you trying to say/point out?

Comment: you're correct I misread it as if the OP were looking to check if both were == to Null I realize that he's missing the `:` in the else check

Comment: @DJKRAZE, just to make sure you understand correctly, the null coalescing operator has no `:` operator, and the OP had no conditional statements. The question was about the utility of having `null` as the second argument to the null coalescing operator, to which the answer is "There is none".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are functionally the same.  It doesn't make sense to write

`x = y ?? null` over `x = y`

If you're curious, the IL code generated by `x = y ?? null` is more complex than the IL code generated from `x = y`.

`x = y ?? null`

```
IL_0014:  ldloc.0     // y
IL_0015:  stloc.2     // CS$0$0000
IL_0016:  ldloca.s    02 // CS$0$0000
IL_0018:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>.get_HasValue
IL_001D:  brtrue.s    IL_002A
IL_001F:  ldloca.s    03 // CS$0$0001
IL_0021:  initobj     System.Nullable<System.Int32>
IL_0027:  ldloc.3     // CS$0$0001
IL_0028:  br.s        IL_0036
IL_002A:  ldloca.s    02 // CS$0$0000
IL_002C:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>.GetValueOrDefault
IL_0031:  newobj      System.Nullable<System.Int32>..ctor
IL_0036:  nop         
IL_0037:  stloc.1     // x
```

`x = y`

```
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     // y
IL_000A:  stloc.1     // x
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is equivalent. Even if you have a [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that's *trying* to provide specific behavior for a [`Coalesce` operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.binaryoperationbinder.operation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `TryBinaryOperation` is never entered. The following code does not print anything.

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic y = new MyDyn(); // or with this null
    dynamic z = new MyDyn();
    object x = y ?? z;
}
public class MyDyn : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryBinaryOperation(
        BinaryOperationBinder binder,
        Object arg,
        out Object result
    )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        if (binder.Operation == ExpressionType.Coalesce)
        {
            result = 3;
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```